# How do I assign permission to access Android serial port using pyserial in kivy?

Tags: python, android, kivy, pyserial

I have written a kivy app for Android that used WiFi to send and receive data through the USB-C port of the device. Using `glob.glob('/dev/tty*')`, I am able to list the available ports (I think) but trying:

```py
serial.Serial(<port_name>)
```

fails with the error:

```
serial.serialutil.SerialException: [Errno 13] could not open port <port_name>: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '<port_name>'
```

I expect I need to manually add the permission somehow (similar to `ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE`), but so far I have not been able to figure out the correct way to do this.

I have tried to manually add the permission through the `buildozer.spec file`. I am not sure that the  permission to do this directly exists. If it does I was unable to find one that worked.

I tried the solution posted here:
[How to find USB devices and communicate with them using pySerial in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51551081/how-to-find-usb-devices-and-communicate-with-them-using-pyserial-in-android)

But I was unable to get it to work. This could definitely be due to me being borderline useless at Java, though.

What is the correct way to do this?